# Using grep to find tables being inserted into using a SQL file

Tags: linux, grep

I can do the following to search a file to find SQL INSERT statements:

```
$ cat my_sql_file.sql | grep INSERT
```

but I want to narrow down the search to find the the **unique** tables that the SQL dump is inserting into.

**EDIT:** I also don't want the results sorted.  I just want the results in the exact order that `grep` found them in :).

How can you do this?

Many thanks :).

Comment: This depends on exactly what's in your SQL file. Please provide a sample.

Comment: The SQL file contains three types of statements:  CREATE TABLE, INSERT INTO and ADD CONSTRAINT.  Note that I can't search using CREATE TABLE (which would be easier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use grep, awk and sort to do this.  Supposing the sql for the insert is something like this:

"Insert into tablename ...... "

you can do:

```
grep -i insert | awk '{print $3}' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 2):

awk can do it very shortly:

if you only want the table names in Insert

```
 awk '/INSERT INTO/ && !a[$3]++{print $3}' input.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -i 'insert into' my_sql_file.txt \
| sed -e 's/.*insert into ([^ ]*).*/\1/i' \
| sort -u
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any standard shell script that allows you to filter for uniq's when the uniq's are non-adjacent.  If you're OK with using a one-liner programming language/script such as Haskell, Perl, or Python then something like this should work:

```
cat file.txt | grep INSERT | ...
```

where ... could be one of:

(in Haskell)

```
ghc -e 'let f o = getLine >>= \s -> if elem s o then f o else putStrLn s >> f (s : o) in f []'
```

Or Perl:

```
perl -e 'my %hash ; while (<>) { if (!$hash{$_}) { print $_; $hash{$_}=True; } }'
```

etc.

Comment: What about just `grep INSERT file.txt` ?

Comment: I followed the form of the original question. Bump that comment up another level.